# Increasing the speed of the python iterator

Tags: python, iterator, gcloud

I have implemented a big query job application in python and deployed in app engine and need some help with increasing the efficiency of the below filter that filter to just the user email that is fed as input

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
bq_conn= discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

job_query_dict = []    


###Create the big query client
client =bigquery.Client(project=project_id)


###List the jobs in the client
jobs = client.list_jobs(all_users=True)   # API request
print( [job for job in list(client.list_jobs(all_users=True)) if job.user_email==user_email][0])
```

How do I print the jobs of the user given in the user_email input better than this ?

Comment: Not sure if this is a copy&paste mistake, but you are executing `list_jobs` twice in your example, which is not necessary. Your list comprehension could be written as `[job for job in jobs if ...]` just fine here, using the response you already have.

Comment: It was just a copy paste thing. Thanks for the answer it worked

Comment: Actually , using pandas dataframe made it faster instead getting the jobs in a list and processing them one by one.

Comment: Why not add your solution as an answer then? It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question and accept your own answer, especially given there are no other answers yet. Bonus points for giving an indication on the performance gain over the code in your question. You could as well delete your question, but you already got an upvote, so better to answer with your solution and not leave it as unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the jobs data as pandas dataframe was faster than accessing from a list

```
t=bigquery_service.jobs().list(projectId=project_id,allUsers=True,projection='full',stateFilter=job_state.lower()).execute()
try:
    tab = pd.DataFrame(t['jobs'])    
except:
    return "No jobs"
```